# hg shelve installed but hg: unknown command 'unshelve'

Tags: mercurial, unshelve, shelving

I installed the shelve extension for hg by adding 'shelve=' to [extensions].  I can verify this by running 'hg help extensions' which has the following in the output:

```
enabled extensions:

 extdiff  command to allow external programs to compare revisions
 fetch    pull, update and merge in one command
 shelve   Manage shelves of pickled objects.
```

I then type 'hg shelve' in a repo of mine, and I get:

```
hg: unknown command 'shelve'
Mercurial Distributed SCM
...
```

I would expect the shelve extension to run...

Mercurial verison is 2.0.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Shelve extension is distributed with Mercurial 2.8 and later, as mentioned [here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShelveExtension).

There is an [older third party shelve extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ThirdPartyShelveExtension) that you can use with Mercurial 2.0.2, but it is not distributed with Mercurial and must be installed separately.

Comment: if it's not installed, then why is it staying the extension is enabled?  If I add "whatever=" to my .hgrc, when I run hg i get: "*** failed to import extension whatever: No module named whatever"  So it must be installed...

Comment: Based on the description "Manage shelves of pickled objects" it looks like it's not the Shelve extension but rather the Python library of the same name used for object persistence: http://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html This is very confusing indeed.

Comment: i just upgraded to the latest version of mercurial.  all is good.

Comment: I'm on mercurial `3.9.1` and I get the same error message.

Comment: It's because plugin by default is disabled. Open "TortoiseHg Workbench" ui client.  Then navigate through menu File->Settings->Extensions. And select "shelve" checkbox press "ok".

Comment: I don't understand how this answers the question