# Mercurial Queues: cannot commit and cannot qpop

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-queue

I have added some debugging stuff to an existing working code and made a mq patch. (The debugging stuff in fact breaks the application, but I need it to debug the features that I add, this is why I want to have one unit responsible for the changes, a patch would be ok.)
Then I have modified the working code, and now I want to commit what I have done.
The idea is to commit the changes but not the debugging stuff.

But it did not work:

```
$ hg ci
abort: cannot commit over an applied mq patch
$ hg qpop
abort: local changes found, refresh first
$ hg qseries
debug-stuff
$ hg qapplied
debug-stuff
```

How do I temporarily unapply the debugging changes and commit the useful changes? (Then I will need to reapply the debugging changes and continue development.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. "hg shelve" to save your uncommitted work
2. qpop the patch
3. "hg unshelve" to restore your feature

then you can commit the feature.

Comment: Yes, it worked. The downside is that Ubuntu Precise uses hg 2.0.2 (and the built-in shelve is there starting from 2.8), so one has to clone the old shelve source as suggested at http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ThirdPartyShelveExtension and checkout a compatible revision. Just enabling the shelve did not work, the reason described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22031147/hg-shelve-installed-but-hg-unknown-command-unshelve

Comment: You can get a newer repo for 3.01 using a ppa from [here](https://launchpad.net/~mercurial-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/releases). Also tortoise from [here](https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/releases).

Answer (score 0):

```
$ hg qnew -f a-lot
$ hg qpop -a
// manually editing .hg/patches/series to swap the two patches
$ hg qpush
```

and now I have the changes as a mq patch, while I want to commit them.

```
$ hg qapplied
a-lot
$ hg qfinish a-lot
patch a-lot finalized without changeset message
$ hg qapplied
$
```

Now 'hg log' shows the changes as committed.

I still wonder if qfinish would do the job without extra manipulations.

Comment: FYI: after `hg qpop -a` you could `hg qpush a-lot --move` instead of editing the series file and then just `hg qfinish a-lot` it.